# How to beat Sky O’ Love Challenge Mission?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

We just tried (me and 2 friends of mine) to beat the *Sky O’ Love mission* in Dungeon of Defenders. We spent an hour and we reach "only" wave 8/10 and we desisted. It was really difficult let the lovers meet.

Do you have any suggestions to speed up the things? I am not sure I can tolerate all this hearts and rainbows for more than 1 straight hour...

Comment: Doubt it - dungeon defenders is notorious for having long, repetitive quests that you can't save or pause.  Around August, a [new quest](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Giraffe_on_Treadmill) was introduced for getting to wave 30 on Monster Fest Insane *(since reduced to wave 25 on any difficulty)*.  Doing this took **literally 9 hours** *(my brother did it THREE TIMES, and the game crashed before saving his results every time)*.

Comment: To better answer this question, it's helpful to know what you have in terms of characters and equipment. But basically from what I've seen, you will need builders to protect your crystals, and 'matchmakers' (the easiest way to get them mobs to fall in love is to aggro them towards the top bridge.) Alternatively, the Portal Gun.

Comment: Yes we tried to build up strong defenses around the hearts. The main problem is to bring boys and girls together. About classes we have a mix of all different types so we can build almost any team if you have suggestions. The only important thing is to be successful in a hour or less because is difficult for some of us to spend more time in a "single session".

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found was to have strong bases around the crystals, have a tank class (or two tanks) kite the lovers together, and the rest just keep the base safe. This mission really is a pain though.